# How can this form of variable assignment work?

Tags: c++, syntax, floating-point

What kind of variable assignment syntax is this? Please explain why this code works the way it does and *how*? It seems that the variables are assigned without the `=` operator. Any subsequent tests reveal that `pi_num` returns `3.14`. Why?

```
  #define SPECIAL_NUMBER 3.14
  cout << "Special number is " << SPECIAL_NUMBER << endl;
  #define SPECIAL_VARIABLE pi_num
  float SPECIAL_VARIABLE = SPECIAL_NUMBER;
  cout << "Pi: " << pi_num << endl;
```

Comment: Those are macros. Look at the preprocessed code.

Comment: Interestingly, there are neither variables nor assignment in this fragment.

Comment: @n.m. Uh, yes there is.
`float pi_num = 3.14;`

Comment: Go read http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1098/preprocessor/3527/macros

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is - you might want to pick up a C++ book.

Comment: @ZanLynx You win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happened is that you have obscured what is going on using macros.

Bear in mind that thje preprocessor does text substitution, and replaces macros with their expansion.   In your code every usage of `SPECIAL_NUMBER` will be replaced by `3.14` and every usage of `SPECIAL_VARIABLE` by `pi_num` BEFORE the code is compiled.

So the compiler sees your code as

```
cout << "Special number is " << 3.14 << endl;
float pi_num = 3.14;
cout << "Pi: " << pi_num << endl;
```

I'll leave the debate alone over whether `float pi_num = 3.14` is an assignment or an initialisation (OP unlikely to understand the distinction).

I assume you're aware that the mathematical quantity known as pi (greek letter) is only approximately equal to `3.14`.

Answer (score 1):

After preprocessing this would look like

```
cout << "Special number is " << 3.14 << endl;
float pi_num = 3.14;
cout << "Pi: " << pi_num << endl;
```

No magic involved.